# Android - AutoCompleteTextView not showing after setText is called

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm having a weird issue with `AutoCompleteTextView`.

I have a `AutoCompleteTextView` that shows suggestions of cities when typing in it.
The list of cities is retrieved from a remote server via `JSON`. When I use the soft keyboard or the `Mic` Button on the soft keyboard, the suggestions work fine. `AutoCompleteTextView` does show the suggested cities.

But, I have a problem when I try to set the text using `myAutoCompleteTextView.setText("Chi")` , the auto complete does not show.. 
I have also tried `myAutoCompleteTextView.append("Chi")` but still no luck..

The adapter is there, its just that the suggestions don't show.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: what you have tried yet?

Comment: Are you not using an Adapter for your AutoCompleteTextView? Show some code.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes you are right there is a bug in `AutocompleteTextview` to show default suggestion using `setText("");` method.

But you can achieve this by adding some more lines of code as below.

```
autoText.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                autoText.showDropDown();
            }
        },500);
        autoText.setText("chi");
        autoText.setSelection(autoText.getText().length());
```

Answer (score 11):

It is **due to filtering**, 
No Need to any extra code for manage it, I found it in very easy and working way.

[Google Dev. Reference link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView#setText(java.lang.CharSequence,%20boolean))

```
autoText.setText("Default Value here",false)
autoText.setSelection(autoText.text.count()) // kotlin
```

as per documentation second parameter you can pass for filtering.

**boolean: If false, no filtering will be performed as a result of this call.**

Comment: Actually I did this but still, when the default value is set, it's showing only that item, not showing the remaining items. When setText() function is set with false as second parameter, all the items in the list should be shown but it's not so.

Comment: This option worked perfect for me as I was having the same issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Biraj Zalavadia's answer work, but you must write to "settext" in Runnable. 
Like this:

```
 mACTextViewEmail.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mACTextViewEmail.showDropDown();    
                mACTextViewEmail.setText("My text is here");
                mACTextViewEmail.setSelection(mACTextViewEmail.getText().length());
            }
        },500);
```

Answer (score 1):

I searched for it and just found this solution that worked so well
[Look at this issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/2012)

```
fun AutoCompleteTextView.showDropdown(adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>?) {
  if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(this.text.toString())){
      adapter?.filter?.filter(null)
  }
}
```

In kotlin language, you can use this extension function.

Comment: Where does the `fun` comes from?

Comment: what do you mean?