# In Android, how can I programmatically set an AutoCompleteTextView at the start of an activity? (Java)

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I'm using the AutoCompleteTextView as an ExposedDropdownMenu per the Google Material Guidelines. First I would like to state that I am able to successfully set the AutoCompleteTextView's text value programmatically by waiting ~300ms after the onCreate() function is called, with the proper values inside of the dropdown suggestion menu. However, when I set the AutoCompleteTextView's text programmatically beforehand (e.g. inside of the onCreate() w/o delay), a weird issue arises where the dropdown menu of the AutoCompleteTextView is empty for some reason (and no it's not because of filtering).

**NOTE: I have modified this code from my original source code to make it easier to understand and less complex. It has not been tested and may have errors.**

```
private String[] VALUES = new String[]{"val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item, VALUES);

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text_view);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        //Do something here when item is selected
    });

    //Here I want to set the text value to something in onCreate()
    //without having to wait a random amount of time
    autoCompleteTextView.setText("val3", false);
}
```

This results in the AutoCompleteTextView's dropdown menu only containing "val3" and no other values from the adapter. At first glance it looks like it's filtering but it's not (note that the filter boolean is set to false). The list only contains "val3". However if I wait ~300ms or so, then it works as expected.

```
private String[] VALUES = new String[]{"val1", "val2", "val3", "val4"};

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(mainActivity.getApplicationContext(), R.layout.dropdown_menu_popup_item, VALUES);

    AutoCompleteTextView autoCompleteTextView = findViewById(R.id.auto_complete_text_view);
    autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, id) -> {
        //Do something here when item is selected
    });

    new AsyncTaskThatWaits300ms().execute();
}

private static class WaitForAutoCompleteTextViews extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        if (dialog != null) {
            this.dialog.setMessage("Waiting 300ms...");
            this.dialog.show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {
            //Do something
            Thread.sleep(300);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "doInBackground error: ", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if (dialog != null) {
            if (dialog.isShowing()) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
        //If I set it here, the text will display with the correct values in the dropdown list, instead of only "val3".
        autoCompleteTextView.setText("val3", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to set text  of a specific item on autocomplete textview by clicking on that item? If it is then 
autoCompleteTextView.setText() will be inner of the onitemclicklistener() method.

Comment: No I do not want to programmatically simulate clicking on an item in the AutoCompleteTextView's dropdown menu. I want to set the text in onCreate() as stated above. It works only if I wait around 300ms after onCreate() which I don't want to do. I'm trying to understand why I have to wait for setText to work correctly.

Comment: autoCompleteTextView.setText("Country")  It means set text default in autocomoletetextview,  which need to set in oncreate().Do it before onitemckicklistener(). Also you can set text in xml on autocomplete textview . is it solve your problem?

Comment: I understand that autoCompleteTextView.setText("my text") sets the text, but setting it in onCreate() or even onResume() will indeed set the text. However, it seems to remove the adapter's values (not from filtering). Also, setting the text before setting the adapter does not work as I end up with the same issue (values from the adapter disappearing).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28184543/android-autocompletetextview-not-showing-after-settext-is-called                                                                                           Follow this link. I think it's match with your problem.

Comment: I've viewed this thread before. His issue was filtering. As I explained above, is not my issue. I am already using the boolean set to false to disable filtering.

Comment: Why you want to use settext in autocomplete? just to show the hints on autocomplete or to off filtering? Please specify.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. I need to be able to set the text of the AutoCompleteTextView and when I click on it afterwards, then I should see all the options. It's an exposeddropdownmenu.

Comment: I can already disable filtering and set the text! Just not immediately at the start of the activity. I have to wait.

Comment: any update how you fixed that?